# I have a third-party asynchronous block in my code. How do I know when it has ended?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit. And `call.enqueue` executes asynchronously. I have a block of code to be executed only after `call.enqueue` has been successfully executed.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Event> call, Response<Event> response) {
            returnedEvent =  response.body();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Event> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewEventActivity.this, "There was some internal error. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //code block to be executed after the thread has been executed.
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_title);
    mStartTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startsAt);
    mEndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endsAt);
    mEventTitle.setText(event.getTitle());
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When `onResponse or onFailure` is excuted means `call.enqueue` has been successfully executed.And you should add your block here.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Event>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Event> call, Response<Event> response) {
        returnedEvent =  response.body();
        //code block to be executed after the thread has been executed.
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        mStartTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startsAt);
        mEndTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endsAt);
        mEventTitle.setText(event.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Event> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(ViewEventActivity.this, "There was some internal error. Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: but isnt there a way to know when this thread has ended? Or some work around? Because I would really like to know it! I dont want to increase code complexity! Thanks

Comment: Then you have to read the Okhttp source code.`CallBack` means the `Call` is finished and give you a feedback.